# Lambda code with least execution time

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have written following code in Nodejs for Lambda and get an output which shows all the lambda function filtered by node and none-node run-time across all regions (as expected ).

But, somehow the code looks bulky with lot of function calls to different regions. Can the code be cut short or can the execution time be decreased in some way?

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var boolValue = true;
    console.log("Only regions with Lambda Functions are being shown");
    var callBackCount;
    callBackCount = 0;
    response = {
        Lambda: []
    };
    usWest_1();
    usWest_2();
    usEast_1();
    euWest_1();
    euCentral_1();
    apSouthEast_1();
    apSouthEast_2();
    apNorthEast_1();
    apNorthEast_2();

    // functions for Clients of Each Region

    function usWest_1() {
        var lambda = new AWS.Lambda({
            apiVersion: '2015-03-31',
            region: 'us-west-1'
        });
        var region = "us-west-1";
        ///// function called getFunctions//////
        getFunctions(lambda, region);
    }

    function usWest_2() {
        var lambda = new AWS.Lambda({
            apiVersion: '2015-03-31',
            region: 'us-west-2'
        });
        var region = "us-west-2";
        ///// function called getFunctions//////
        getFunctions(lambda, region);
    }

    function usEast_1() {
        var lambda = new AWS.Lambda({
            apiVersion: '2015-03-31',
            region: 'us-east-1'
        });
        var region = "us-east-1";
        ///// function called getFunctions//////
        getFunctions(lambda, region);
    }

    function euWest_1() {
        var lambda = new AWS.Lambda({
            apiVersion: '2015-03-31',
            region: 'eu-west-1'
        });
        var region = "eu-west-1";
        ///// function called getFunctions//////
        getFunctions(lambda, region);
    }

    function euCentral_1() {
        var lambda = new AWS.Lambda({
            apiVersion: '2015-03-31',
            region: 'eu-central-1'
        });
        var region = "eu-central-1";
        ///// function called getFunctions//////
        getFunctions(lambda, region);
    }

    function apSouthEast_1() {
        var lambda = new AWS.Lambda({
            apiVersion: '2015-03-31',
            region: 'ap-southeast-1'
        });
        var region = "ap-southeast-1";
        ///// function called getFunctions//////
        getFunctions(lambda, region);
    }

    function apSouthEast_2() {
        var lambda = new AWS.Lambda({
            apiVersion: '2015-03-31',
            region: 'ap-southeast-2'
        });
        var region = "ap-southeast-2";
        ///// function called getFunctions//////
        getFunctions(lambda, region);
    }

    function apNorthEast_1() {
        var lambda = new AWS.Lambda({
            apiVersion: '2015-03-31',
            region: 'ap-northeast-1'
        });
        var region = "ap-northeast-1";
        ///// function called getFunctions//////
        getFunctions(lambda, region);
    }

    function apNorthEast_2() {
        var lambda = new AWS.Lambda({
            apiVersion: '2015-03-31',
            region: 'ap-northeast-2'
        });
        var region = "ap-northeast-2";
        ///// function called getFunctions//////
        getFunctions(lambda, region);
    }

    function getFunctions(lambda, region) {
        var regionName = region;
        var callbackData = {};
        var params = {};
        lambda.listFunctions(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err, err.stack);
            } // an error occurred
            else {
                callbackData = JSON.stringify(data);
            } // successful response
            getNodeFunctions(callbackData, regionName);
        });
    }

    function getNodeFunctions(callbackData, regionName) {
        var allFunctions = {
            region: "",
            nodeFunctions: [],
            noneNodeFunctions: []
        };
        var paramData = (JSON.parse(callbackData));
        if (paramData.Functions[0] === undefined) {
            boolValue = false; // if no function in this region
            viewData(allFunctions, boolValue, regionName);
        } else {
            boolValue = true;
            paramData.Functions.forEach(function(functs) {
                if (functs.Runtime.startsWith("node")) {

                    var names = {
                        "FunctionName": '',
                        "Runtime": '',
                        "FunctionArn": '',
                        "LastModified": ''

                    };
                    names.FunctionName = (functs.FunctionName);
                    names.Runtime = (functs.Runtime);
                    names.FunctionArn = (functs.FunctionArn);
                    names.LastModified = (functs.LastModified);
                    allFunctions.nodeFunctions.push(names);
                } else {
                    var noneNode = {

                        "FunctionName": '',
                        "Runtime": '',
                        "FunctionArn": '',
                        "LastModified": ''

                    };
                    noneNode.FunctionName = (functs.FunctionName);
                    noneNode.Runtime = (functs.Runtime);
                    noneNode.FunctionArn = (functs.FunctionArn);
                    noneNode.LastModified = (functs.LastModified);
                    allFunctions.noneNodeFunctions.push(noneNode);
                }
            });
        }
        viewData(allFunctions, boolValue, regionName);
    }

    function viewData(allFunctions, boolValue, regionName) {
        callBackCount++;
        var testVal = boolValue;
        var thisRegion = regionName;
        var viewAllFunctions = allFunctions;
        viewAllFunctions.region = thisRegion;
        if (testVal === true) {
            response.Lambda.push(viewAllFunctions);
        } else {
            //  regions without lambda function
        }
        if (callBackCount == 9 && response.Lambda[0] === undefined) {
            //console.log("weird");
        } else if (callBackCount == 9 && response.Lambda[0] !== undefined) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
            callback(null, response);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(event));
        } else {
            //console.log("something else");
        }
    }


};
```

**UPDATE 1**

As suggested by [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/174777/john-rotenstein), I added regions to an array. It looks more cleaner now. but still it contains few loops which can be eliminated. Like: to return callback, condition is checked whether all regions are executed or not, if callback is kept outside loop, it will return null response, as asynchronous Node will execute it first. Promises can be used to overcome that situation, but still not sure how to use promises when loops are nested and execution time is a concern. Also, can there be a way other than promises this can be done without adding more cost in execution?

```
 var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
 exports.handler = (event, context, callback) =>
 {
    var boolValue = true;
    console.log("Only regions with Lambda Functions are being shown");
    var callBackCount;
    callBackCount = 0;
    response = {
            Lambda: []
    };
    var regionNames = ['us-west-1', 'us-west-2', 'us-east-1', 'eu-west-1', 'eu-central-1', 'ap-southeast-1',
            'ap-southeast-2', 'ap-northeast-1', 'ap-northeast-2'
    ];
    regionNames.forEach(function(region)
    {
            getFunctions(region);
    });

    function getFunctions(region)
    {
            var regionName = region;
            var info = {
                    apiVersion: '2015-03-31',
                    region: ''
            };
            info.region = regionName;
            var lambda = new AWS.Lambda(info);
            var callbackData = {};
            var params = {};
            lambda.listFunctions(params, function(err, data)
            {
                    if (err)
                    {
                            console.log(err, err.stack);
                    } // an error occurred
                    else
                    {
                            callbackData = JSON.stringify(data);
                    } // successful response
                    getNodeFunctions(callbackData, regionName);
            });
    }

    function getNodeFunctions(callbackData, regionName)
    {
            var allFunctions = {
                    region: "",
                    nodeFunctions: [],
                    noneNodeFunctions: []
            };
            var paramData = (JSON.parse(callbackData));
            if (paramData.Functions[0] === undefined)
            {
                    boolValue = false;
                    viewData(allFunctions, boolValue, regionName);
            }
            else
            {
                    boolValue = true;
                    paramData.Functions.forEach(function(functs)
                    {
                            if (functs.Runtime.startsWith("node"))
                            {
                                    var names = {
                                            "FunctionName": '',
                                            "Runtime": '',
                                            "FunctionArn": '',
                                            "LastModified": ''
                                    };
                                    names.FunctionName = (functs.FunctionName);
                                    names.Runtime = (functs.Runtime);
                                    names.FunctionArn = (functs.FunctionArn);
                                    names.LastModified = (functs.LastModified);
                                    allFunctions.nodeFunctions.push(names);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                    var noneNode = {
                                            "FunctionName": '',
                                            "Runtime": '',
                                            "FunctionArn": '',
                                            "LastModified": ''
                                    };
                                    noneNode.FunctionName = (functs.FunctionName);
                                    noneNode.Runtime = (functs.Runtime);
                                    noneNode.FunctionArn = (functs.FunctionArn);
                                    noneNode.LastModified = (functs.LastModified);
                                    allFunctions.noneNodeFunctions.push(noneNode);
                            }
                    });
            }
            viewData(allFunctions, boolValue, regionName);
    }

    function viewData(allFunctions, boolValue, regionName)
    {
            callBackCount++;
            var testVal = boolValue;
            var thisRegion = regionName;
            var viewAllFunctions = allFunctions;
            viewAllFunctions.region = thisRegion;
            if (testVal === true)
            {
                    response.Lambda.push(viewAllFunctions);
            }
            else
            {
                    //  regions without lambda function
            }
            if (callBackCount == 9 && response.Lambda[0] === undefined)
            {
                    //console.log("weird");
            }
            else if (callBackCount == 9 && response.Lambda[0] !== undefined)
            {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                    callback(null, response);
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(event));
            }
            else
            {
                    //console.log("something else");
            }
    }
};
```

Comment: For a start, you could create an array of region names and then just call one function for each value in the array. You also seem to be handling Node and non-Node functions exactly the same, so there's no need for different code. Also, you could consider using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) rather than writing a Lambda function.

Comment: I have exposed an api through api-gateway which invokes this lambda function and returns callback in JSON format. the purpose of writing different code primarily was to sort the JSON output as:Lambda->region>node/non node functions array.
something like: `{
       "Lambda": [
        {
            "region": "us-west-2",
            "nodeFunctions": [
                {
                    "FunctionName": "getAllI",
                  }]}]

Comment: Have you considered using [`list-functions`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/list-functions.html)?

Comment: Yeah but i am not considering CLI, as I want this to be invoked using api-gateway and callback data can be used for view/UI